# SQL GROUP BY problem. Request return incorrect table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Have a table
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6e8b3/176)
Or

```
CREATE TABLE public.products
(product_id INT4,
sku INT4 NOT NULL,
mp VARCHAR,
cost FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
finish_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO public.products
(product_id, sku, mp, cost, start_date, finish_date)
VALUES
(221, 378264, 'ozon', 47.5, '2023-02-27 21:47', '2023-02-28 00:00'),
(147, 235234, 'wb', 524.22, '2023-04-02 15:23', '2023-04-10 00:00'),
(11, 124321, 'yandex', 214.0, '2023-01-04 11:02', '2023-01-11 00:00'),
(94, 145434, 'wb', 118.24, '2023-02-19 17:11', '2023-02-21 00:00'),
(543, 124432, 'yandex', 749.0, '2023-02-12 09:12', '2023-02-15 00:00'),
(45, 798623, 'ozon', 347.12, '2023-01-13 13:45', '2023-01-16 00:00'),
(47, 123486, 'ozon', 522.2, '2023-04-01 12:45', '2023-04-16 00:00'),
(89, 123135, 'yandex', 347.8, '2023-04-02 11:13', '2023-04-16 00:00');

CREATE TABLE public.events
(sku INT4 NOT NULL,
mp VARCHAR,
status VARCHAR,
quantity INT4 NOT NULL,
create_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO public.events
(sku, mp, status, quantity, create_date)
VALUES
(378264, 'ozon', 'заказ товара', 2, '2023-02-28 14:47'),
(378264, 'ozon', 'покупка товара', 1, '2023-02-28 19:25'),
(235234, 'wb', 'заказ товара', 10, '2023-04-03 11:10'),
(235234, 'wb', 'покупка товара', 2, '2023-04-03 19:13'),
(124321, 'yandex', 'заказ товара', 6, '2023-01-05 10:00'),
(124321, 'yandex', 'покупка товара', 2, '2023-01-05 16:17'),
(145434, 'wb', 'заказ товара', 1, '2023-02-20 14:37'),
(145434, 'wb', 'отмена', 1, '2023-02-20 15:19'),
(124432, 'yandex', 'заказ товара', 4, '2023-02-13 09:12'),
(124432, 'yandex', 'покупка товара', 4, '2023-02-13 10:22'),
(798623, 'ozon', 'заказ товара', 10, '2023-01-14 12:21'),
(798623, 'ozon', 'покупка товара', 8, '2023-01-14 13:10'),
(123486, 'ozon', 'заказ товара', 12, '2023-04-02 14:52'),
(123486, 'ozon', 'покупка товара', 3, '2023-04-02 14:33'),
(123135, 'yandex', 'заказ товара', 5, '2023-04-04 09:00'),
(123135, 'yandex', 'покупка товара', 4, '2023-04-04 09:12');

CREATE TABLE public.stock 
(product_id INT4 NOT NULL,
stock_code VARCHAR NOT NULL,
quantity INT4,
update_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO public.stock
(product_id, stock_code, quantity, update_date)
VALUES
(221, 'OZON_ЦЕНТРАЛЬНЫЙ_СКЛАД', 24, '2023-02-26 00:00'),
(147, 'WB_ХОРВУГИНО', 12, '2023-04-03 00:00'),
(11, 'YANDEX_ХИМКИ', 340, '2023-01-03 00:00'),
(94, 'WB_ДОМОДЕДОВО', 15, '2023-02-18 00:00'),
(543, 'YANDEX_МЯКИНИНО', 27, '2023-02-11 00:00'),
(45, 'OZON_ЧЕРТАНОВО', 74, '2023-01-12 00:00'),
(47, 'ozon', 52, '2023-04-01 00:00'),
(89, 'yandex', 9, '2023-04-01 00:00');
```

and request

```
WITH ordered AS
  (SELECT create_date, mp, SUM(quantity)::DECIMAL AS sum_ordered 
  FROM public.events
  WHERE status = 'заказ товара'
  AND DATE_PART('month', create_date) = DATE_PART('month', CURRENT_DATE)
  GROUP BY create_date, mp),

sales AS 
  (SELECT create_date, mp, SUM(quantity)::DECIMAL AS sum_sale 
  FROM public.events
  WHERE status = 'покупка товара'
  AND DATE_PART('month', create_date) = DATE_PART('month', CURRENT_DATE)
  GROUP BY create_date, mp)

SELECT
  b.create_date AS Date,
  b.mp AS Marketplace,
  ROUND(SUM(a.cost::DECIMAL * quantity::DECIMAL), 2) AS day_revenue_sum,
  CONCAT(ROUND(sales.sum_sale::DECIMAL / ordered.sum_ordered::DECIMAL, 2) * 100, '%') AS ratio
FROM
  ordered, sales, public.products AS a
RIGHT JOIN 
  public.events AS b
  ON a.sku = b.sku
WHERE 
  status = 'покупка товара' AND
  DATE_PART('month', b.create_date) = DATE_PART('month', CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY
  b.mp, Date
ORDER BY 
  day_revenue_sum DESC
```

I cant make this request without GROUP BY **ratio**, but with group by ratio i get incorrect table with a lot of rows.

[image: incorrect table]

Im trying to make third sub_query with ratio, but its didnt work and makes me do GROUP BY ratio again. The final table should be consists of **three rows** (three marketplaces) with columns:
 **date**, **marketplace**, **daily_revenue**, **sale_order_ratio**.
 Please help.

Comment: Hi - for a start, you shouldn’t mix join syntax: stick to one (and that should be ansi join syntax as the other syntax hasn’t been good practice for 30+ years). You are also generating a Cartesian product with these tables “ordered, sales, public.products”

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a19f9/40  another example with Cartesian product, i don't understand why its happen

Comment: Again, you are still using outdated join syntax and you are not restricting those joins - so every record in the 3 tables is being joined to every record in the other tables. If you used ansi join syntax this would be much more obvious

Comment: You mean ON? In question request i used that

"RIGHT JOIN 
  public.events AS b
  ON a.sku = b.sku"

Comment: In my first comment I showed you which tables were using outdated join syntax and were generating a cartesian product: “from ordered, sales, public.products”

Comment: I finally get it! And that helped!) Thank you veeeeeeeeeery much Bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is searching how to solve this problem and found this question. Read comments under question first and here is the answer:

**incorrect**

```
FROM
  ordered, sales, public.products AS a
```

**correct**

```
FROM
  public.products AS a
RIGHT JOIN 
  public.events AS b
  ON a.sku = b.sku
JOIN ordered
  ON b.sku = ordered.sku
JOIN sales
  ON b.sku = sales.sku
```